# Precision to drand48

Tags: c++

How can I add precision to drand48() in C++?
I am using it in a function like:

```
double x = drand48()%1000+1;
```

to generate numbers below 1000.
But then I get this error:

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘double’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator%’
```

This does not happen when I use:

```
double x = rand()%1000+1;
```

Why and what is the difference between rand() and drand48()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

drand48 returns a double in the range of 0.0 to 1.0.  You want to multiply that by the range you're looking to generate. `double x = drand48() * 1000.0`

Answer (score 8):

`drand48` returns a number from the interval `[0.0, 1.0)`. Are you looking for a number between 1 and 1000? In this case, you need to multiply by 999 and add 1.

Actually, what are you expecting?

Comment: I was needing a number between 0 and 1000. I was confused about how drand48() is different from rand(). Now its clear. Thanks, all.

Comment: Not precise enough. The first reference I found had [0,1]. It's actually [0,1).

Answer (score 5):

`drand48()` returns a `double`, whereas `rand()` returns `int`.

Furthermore, `drand48()` returns a value that's distributed between `[0.0, 1.0)`, so your formula needs to change:

```
double x = drand48() * 1000.0 + 1; // floating-point values from [1, 1001)
```

or

```
double x = (int)(drand48() * 1000.0) + 1; // integer values from [1, 1000]
```

You could either scale the result of `drand48()` as above, or use `lrand48()` with your existing formula.